# Let X and Y be jointly normal random variables with $X,Y \sim N(0, 1)$ and correlation 1/2. Eval $\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{X} \ | \ Y=1 \right]$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, definite-integrals, expected-value

I need help with this question: Let X and Y be jointly normal random variables with $X, Y \sim N(0, 1)$ and correlation 1/2. Evaluate $\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{X} \ | \ Y=1  \right]$.

Here's where I'm stuck: we know that:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{X} \ | \ Y=1  \right] = \int_{ -\infty }^{\infty} e^{x} f_{X|Y}(x|1) dx
$$
And that:
$$
f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x, y)}{f_{Y}(y)}
$$
$$
f_{X,Y}(x, y) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{3}} e^{-\frac{2}{3}(x^2 + y^2 - xy)}
$$
$$
f_{Y}(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}
$$
Plugging all the numbers, I get to the following integral:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{X} \ | \ Y=1  \right] = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3\pi} } \int_{ -\infty }^{\infty}  e^{-\frac{1}{6} (4x^2 - 10x + 1) } dx
$$
and I don't know what's the best approach to solve it (actually any approach). Wolfram tells me that this magically solves to $e^{7/8}$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Complete the square in the exponent and then use the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: The intuitition here is that with a joint normal distribution, X given Y is also Gaussian. So this is fundamentally the same problem as any log normal distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are told $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ are jointly normal with correlation $\rho$.  Observe that $X-\rho Y\sim N(0,1-\rho^2)$ and $Y$ are jointly normal and uncorrelated and hence independent. Thus,

$$\begin{align}E[e^X|Y=1]&=E[e^{X-\rho Y}e^{\rho Y}|Y=1]\\
&=E[e^{X-\rho Y}e^{\rho}|Y=1]\\
&=e^{\rho}E[e^{X-\rho Y}]\quad (\text{by independence})\\
&=e^{\rho}e^{\frac{1}{2}(1-\rho^2)}\quad (\text{using MGF})\\
\end{align}.$$

For $\rho=1/2$, this simplifies to the desired solution, $e^{7/8}.$